# Looking forrecords in a database that contain a specific string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following "tweets" table:

```
tweet_id  user_id  text
---------------------------------------------------
1         2        this is a tweet with (TAG} in it
2         2        tweet without a TAG
3         2        {TAG} another {TAG} tweet
4         4        look at my {TAG} and weep!
```

I want to count, for each user, the number of tweets that contains `{TAG}` at least once. The tag could be anywhere in the tweet: at the beginning, in the middle or at the end (read: not followed by a space or anything). The table has millions of records, so I'm looking for an efficient way to do this. My first attempt was

```
SELECT COUNT(tweet_id) FROM tweets WHERE `text` LIKE '%{TAG}%' AND user_id = 2
```

but this returns 0 while, in this example, it was expected to return 2. So two questions: (i) what am I doing wrong and (ii) is there a more efficient way to do this?

[EDIT]

I would like to insert the result into the "users" table:

```
user_id  tweets_with_tag
2        2
3        0
4        9
```

Is it possible to count and insert in the same query?

Comment: how often would you like to insert such values into "users" table? Maybe you want to use [View](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) instead of regular table?

Comment: I have about 100.000 users and a few million tweets. I only have to do this once - it is for research purposes on a static dataset, instead of something for a live application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Insert:

```
INSERT INTO users(user_id, tweets_with_tag) 
SELECT COUNT(tweet_id) as 'tweets_with_tag',
[user_id] as 'user_id'
FROM tweets 
WHERE text LIKE '%{TAG}%'
GROUP BY user_id
```

**Edit: If the User table already exists do the following**

```
UPDATE users
SET tweets_with_tag = (
    SELECT COUNT(tweet_id) as 'tweets_with_tag'
    FROM tweets 
    WHERE text LIKE '%{TAG}%' and user_id = users.user_id
    GROUP BY user_id)
```

Comment: I made a mistake: the USER table is an existing table. I have created a 'tweets_with_tag' column, and it needs to only be updated. Am I doing this right? UPDATE users SET tweets_with_tag = SELECT COUNT(tweet_id) AS 'tweet_with_tag' FROM tweets WHERE text LIKE ' {TAG}%' GROUP BY user_id

Comment: @Reveller check my edit, I've included the code for the existing User table :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first entry in tweets has (TAG}. That's why it doesn't get picked up. The query returns 1 as is correct.

As far as the insert goes, you can use the INSERT INTO.. SELECT construct. A good reference is at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html